# RxJava - get rid of blockingGet(), but wait with return statement until onComplete is called

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room, okhttp

I have function `fun getToken(): Maybe<String>` in my `TokenRepository`

I'm using it in my Interceptor like that

```
class AuthorizationInterceptor(private val tokenRepository: TokenRepository) : Interceptor {

    private val authorization = "apiToken"

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val original = chain.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        tokenRepository.getToken().blockingGet()?.let { requestBuilder.header(authorization, it) }
        requestBuilder.method(original.method(), original.body())

        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

However, I would like to get rid of `blockingGet()`, because it's not a good practice and I needed to add `.allowMainThreadQueries()` in my Room Db config.

I've replaced it like that

```
override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

    val original = chain.request()
    val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()

    tokenRepository.getToken()
        .subscribe(
        { token ->
            token?.let { requestBuilder.header(authorization, it) }
            requestBuilder.method(original.method(), original.body())
        },
        {},
        {}
    )

    return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
}
```

But it won't wait with return till I have my token.

How to implement it correctly that it will return from the function after `onComplete` in my subscription is called?

Comment: Why do you consider `blockingGet()` bad practice? There are use cases when it is useful, including this use case.

Comment: to use `blockingGet()` I need to add `.allowMainThreadQueries()` in my Room db config. I like for other use cases that room will force to do operations in background

Comment: "I needed to add .allowMainThreadQueries() in my Room Db config" -- that would indicate that something is seriously messed up in either your repository or your networking call. An interceptor should not be being called on the main application thread. "How to implement it correctly that it will return from the function after onComplete in my subscription is called?" -- you can't. You might want to pre-load the token before doing any network I/O.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are perfectly right. It threw the exception in the other place that also was using `blockingGet`. In that case, I'm leaving `blockingGet` in my Interceptor. Thank you!

Comment: If you want a blocking call here in your interceptor, you could consider just adding another function to your DAO. `getToken()` would be the Rx one, `getTokenBlocking()` would just return the String, not `Maybe<String>`. That saves a bunch of Rx overhead that isn't doing you any good.

Comment: You're using RX wrong, this is not the way it is meant to be used. You create a top-level reactive chain that is subscribed to once. You present code is no better than writing a blocking function to get the token.

Comment: @PrashantPandey so give an example how I should use it in that use case, please.